# How does prepareForSegue work? (passing data to next view controller)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm learning Swift and iOS development and I found that a very convenient way to pass data between view controllers is using the `segue.destinationViewController` property in the `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method. Now, while I understood how to use it, I didn't get exactly how it works.

Consider the following code taken from [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let mealDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MealViewController

        if let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedMealCell)!
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("Adding new meal.")
    }
}
```

I was wondering how can a property set on `mealDetailViewController` (an instance of `MealViewController` stored in local constant, for what I (wrongly?) understood) be found in the view controller that actually manages the next view when prepareForSegue returns.

Could you explain how does this work and what happens when a segue is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code or some built-in button action triggers a segue an instance of `UIStoryboardSegue` is created. In that segue there are a few interesting properties like the `destinationViewController` for example. Since you did setup the segue in the storyboard the OS knows to which ViewController you want to transition. Therefore it creates an instance of that ViewController, in this case an instance of `MealViewController` and stores that controller in the property `destinationViewController`. It then does some other stuff that you do not need to worry about.

The important part is then calling the method `prepareForSegue` on the currently presented ViewController, which in this case is the exact method you posted. That controller can now go ahead an decide wether or not it wants to pass data along or print something or send something to the server since you are finished with this controller, or whatever you want.

It is very important to note that you do not *create* an instance of `MealViewController` here, but retrieve the already created one and store it a local constant (as you correctly observed).

When your method returns the caller / UIKit goes ahead and does some more stuff eventually leading to the actual animated transitioning happening on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I stupidly hadn't realized is that both the local constant (`mealDetailViewController` in this case) and `segue.destinationViewController` refer to the same instance of the view controller (`MealViewController`). 
It was much simpler than I thought.

Comment: @LorenzoRossi exactly, you get the reference to the exact same instance of the `MealViewController` aka the `destinationViewController`.